# How can i stack buttons on top of each other using flex box

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm learning HTML and CSS and I'm kinda in trouble with CSS flex box
so I have this code

```css
:root {
  --blue-color: #18479f;
  --gold-color: #e8b224;
}
html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.sub-hero{
  height: 60vh;

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.buttons-all{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
 position: relative;
 
}
.slideshow-mid{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
  border: var(--blue-color) 3px solid;


}
.slideshow-mid img{
  width: 550px;
  
}

.buttons-all .buttons{


}

.buttons .button1{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid var(--blue-color) 3px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 20px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  /* margin-left: 1300px;
  margin-top: 100px; */
  box-shadow: 0px 5px var(--gold-color);

}
.buttons .button1:hover{
  transform: translateY(5px);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px var(--gold-color);
}
.buttons .button1 a:hover span{
  color: var(--gold-color);
}
.buttons .button1 a{
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 80px;
 padding-top: 46px;


 
 }
.buttons .button1 .home-fire{
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 85px;
  padding: 0;

}
.buttons .button1 .fire1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 43px;
  height: 25px;  
  animation: fire 2s ease-in-out infinite;
 }
 .buttons .button1 .fire3{
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 25px;  
  animation: fire 5s ease-in-out .5s infinite;
 
 }
 .buttons .button1 .fire2{
  position: absolute;
  left: 73px;
  top: 0px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 20px;  
  animation: fire 2s ease-in-out .2s infinite;
 
 }
 @keyframes fire{
  0%{
    opacity: 50%;
    transform: translateX(3px);
  }
  10%{
    opacity: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-3px);

  
  }
  20%{
    opacity: 50%;
    transform: translateX(3px);

  }
  30%{
    opacity: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-3px);

  }
  40%{
    opacity: 50%;
    transform: translateX(3px);

  }
  50%{
    opacity: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-3px);

  }
  60%{
    opacity: 50% ; 
    transform: translateX(3px);

  }
  70%{
    opacity: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-3px);

  
  }
  80%{
    opacity: 50%;
    transform: translateX(3px);

  
  }
  90%{
    opacity: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-3px);

  } 
   100%{
    opacity: 50%;
    transform: translateX(3px);

  }

}
 .buttons .button1 span {
   font-family: vazirbold;
   font-size: 1.3rem;
   padding-left: 140px;
   color: var(--blue-color);
   
  
 
 }



.buttons .button2{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: solid var(--blue-color) 3px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 20px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  /* margin-left: 1075px;
  margin-top: -85px; */
  box-shadow: 0px 5px var(--gold-color);

}
.buttons .button2:hover{
  transform: translateY(5px);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px var(--gold-color);
}

.buttons .button2 a{
  position: relative;
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 80px;
 padding-top: 46px;
 }
 .buttons .button2 a:hover span{
   color: var(--gold-color);
 }
 .buttons .button2 .barbari-icons{
   display: flex;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden; 
   align-items: center;
   height: 80px;
   width: 95px;
   top: 22px;
   right: 95px;
 

 
 }
.buttons .button2 .truck{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  animation: truck 3s ease-in-out infinite 1.5s;

}
.buttons .button2 .plane{
  position: absolute;
  left: 43px;
  height: 50px;  
  padding-left: 25px;
  animation: plane 3s ease-in-out infinite;
 }
 @keyframes plane{
   0%{
     transform: translateX(-125px);
   }
   100%{
    transform: translateX(40px);
  }
  
 }
 @keyframes truck{
  0%{
    transform: translateX(-60px);
  }
  50%{
   transform: translateX(20px);
 }
 100%{
   transform: translateX(100px);
 }
 
}
 .buttons .button2 span {
   font-family: vazirbold;
   font-size: 1.3rem;
   padding-left: 85px;  
   color: var(--blue-color);
  }


  .buttons .button3{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: solid var(--blue-color) 3px;
    width: 525px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 20px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    /* margin-left: 1075px;
    margin-top: 25px; */
    box-shadow: 0px 5px var(--gold-color);
  
  }
  .buttons .button3:hover{
    transform: translateY(5px);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px var(--gold-color);
  }
  
  .buttons .button3 a{
    position: relative;
   text-decoration: none;
   height: 80px;
   padding-top: 40px;
   }
   .buttons .button3 a:hover span{
     color: var(--gold-color);
   }
  
  .buttons .button3 .car-normal{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    height: 48px;
    right: 150px ;
  
  }
  .buttons .button3 .car-hitting {
    position: absolute;
    height: 78px;  
    bottom: -6px;
    left: -92px;
    animation: car-hitting 3s ease-in-out infinite;
   }
   .buttons .button3 .shield {
    position: absolute;
    right: 210px;
    height: 40px;  
    bottom: 65px;
    animation: shield 3s ease-in-out infinite;
   }
   .buttons .button3 .explosion {
    position: absolute;
    right: 170px;
    height: 40px;  
    bottom: 13px;
    animation:  2s ease-in-out infinite;
    padding-left: 25px;
    animation: explosion 3s ease-in-out infinite;
   }
   @keyframes shield{
     0%{
       transform: scale(20%);
     }
     30%{
      transform: scale(100%);
    }
    100%{
      transform: scale(20%);
    }
    
   }
   @keyframes car-hitting{
    0%{
      transform: translateX(90px);
    }
    30%{
     transform: translateX(320px);
   }
 
   100%{
    transform: translateX(90px);

   }

   
  }
  @keyframes explosion{
    0%{
      transform: scale(0%)
    }
    25%{
     transform: scale(0%);
   }
 
   32%{
    transform: scale(100%);
    opacity: 1;

   }
   65%{
     opacity: 0;
   }
   100%{
     opacity: 0;
   }
  }
   .buttons .button3 span {
     font-family: vazirbold;
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     color: var(--blue-color);
     padding: 0 0 0 380px;

    }
  

    .buttons .button4{
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      border: solid var(--blue-color) 3px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 80px;
      border-radius: 20px; 
      overflow: hidden;
      /* margin-left: 1400px;
      margin-top: 25px; */
      box-shadow: 0px 5px var(--gold-color);
    
    }
    .buttons .button4:hover{
      transform: translateY(5px);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px var(--gold-color);
    }
    
    .buttons .button4 a{
      position: relative;
     text-decoration: none;
     height: 80px;
     padding-top: 46px;
     }
     .buttons .button4 a:hover span{
       color: var(--gold-color);
     }
    .buttons .button4 .home-heart{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 35px;
      height: 55px;
      padding-right: 25px;
      animation: home 1s ease-in-out infinite ;
      transform-origin: center;
    
    }
    .buttons .button4 .family{
      position: absolute;
      left: -13px;
      bottom: 35px;
      height: 30px;  
      padding-left: 25px;
      animation: family 1s ease-in-out infinite;

     }
     @keyframes home{
       0%{
         transform: scale(1);
       }
       50%{
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }
      100%{
        transform: scale(1);
      }
     }
     @keyframes family{
      0%{
        opacity: 20%;

      }
      50%{
      opacity: 100%;

     }
     100%{
       opacity: 20%;

     }
     
    }
     .buttons .button4 span {
       font-family: vazirbold;
       font-size: 1.3rem;
       padding-left: 85px;  
       color: var(--blue-color);
      }
    
    

      .buttons .button5{
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        border: solid var(--blue-color) 3px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 80px;
        border-radius: 20px; 
        overflow: hidden;
        /* margin-left: 1075px;
        margin-top: -86px; */
        box-shadow: 0px 5px var(--gold-color);
      
      }
      .buttons .button5:hover{
        transform: translateY(5px);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px var(--gold-color);
      }
      .buttons .button5 a:hover span{
        color: var(--gold-color);
      }
      .buttons .button5 a{
       text-decoration: none;
       height: 80px;
       padding-top: 46px;
      
      
       
       }
      .buttons .button5 .cloud{
        position: absolute;
        right: 215px;
        bottom: 51px;
        height: 25px;
        padding: 0;
        animation: cloud 2s ease-in-out infinite;
      
      }
      .buttons .button5 .umbrella{
        position: absolute;
        left: 43px;
        height: 45px;  
        animation: umbrella 2s ease-in-out infinite;
       }
       .buttons .button5 .ppl1{
        position: absolute;
        left: 70px;
        bottom: 0px;
        height: 28px;  
        /* animation: fire 5s ease-in-out .5s infinite; */
       
       }
       .buttons .button5 .ppl2{
        position: absolute;
        left: 48px;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 28px;  
        /* animation: fire 2s ease-in-out .2s infinite; */
       
       }
       
       @keyframes cloud{
        0%{
          transform: scale(1);
          opacity: 100%;
        }
        50%{
         transform: scale(1.2);
         opacity: 50%;
       }
       100%{
         transform: scale(1);
         opacity: 100%;
       }
      }
      @keyframes umbrella{
        0%{
          transform: rotate(5deg)
        }
        50%{
         transform: rotate(-5deg);
       }
       100%{
         transform: rotate(10deg);
       }
      }
       .buttons .button5 span {
         font-family: vazirbold;
         font-size: 1.3rem;
         padding-left: 140px;
         color: var(--blue-color);
         
        
       
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="sub-hero" id="sub-hero">
      <div class="buttons-all">
        <div class="slideshow-mid">
          <img src="img/bime-banner-site.png" alt="cc" />
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <div class="button1">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
              <img class="home-fire" src="img/home.svg" alt="home" />
              <img class="fire1" src="img/fire.svg" alt="fire" />
              <img class="fire2" src="img/fire.svg" alt="fire" />
              <img class="fire3" src="img/fire.svg" alt="fire" />
              <span>بیمه آتش سوزی</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="button2">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
              <div class="barbari-icons">
                <img class="truck" src="img/truck.svg" alt="truck" />
                <img class="plane" src="img/plane.svg" alt="plane" />
              </div>
              <span>بیمه باربری</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="button3">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
              <img class="car-normal" src="img/normal-car.svg" alt="car" />
              <img class="car-hitting" src="img/hitting-car.svg" alt="car" />
              <img src="img/explosion.png" alt="explosion" class="explosion" />
              <img src="img/shield.svg" alt="shield" class="shield" />

              <span>بیمه اتومبیل</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="button4">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
              <img
                class="home-heart"
                src="img/home-with-heart.svg"
                alt="home"
              />
              <img class="family" src="img/family.svg" alt="family" />

              <span>بیمه عمر</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="button5">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
              <img class="ppl1" src="img/ppl1.svg" alt="ppl" />
              <img class="ppl2" src="img/ppl2.svg" alt="ppl2" />
              <img src="img/umbrella.svg" alt="umbrella" class="umbrella" />
              <img src="img/cloud.svg" alt="cloud" class="cloud" />

              <span>بیمه مسئولیت</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="button6"></div>
          <div class="button7"></div>
          <div class="button8"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

and I want my buttons to stack on each other like this

[image]

but the problem is I don't know how to set them and how to set the width of every column so only that amount of space is needed (like I want my columns to be 550px and if 2 buttons can fit then be it and if not then only one button be in that column). now I have seen a lot of YouTube videos and it got me more confused
pls help me !

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I think you want to set the following in css:  `.buttons-all .buttons { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; width: 550px; }`

Comment: Do you want it so that say any button over a certain width takes a whole line and any button that is under a certain width can share a line (if there is space)? It is not clear from your description how your buttons are sized. And does the order of buttons matter?

Comment: for example, I have a div with a width of 500px
and I have 2 buttons  with width of 300px 200px 490px
I want it to automatically put the 300px and 200px in one column and the other button below them. and if there's even more buttons then do the same with others

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem". The current title is just some keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a parent container and use flexBox inside and set its direction to **row** that means if there is more child always add them in same row and we use `flex-wrap: wrap;` to let if some of the boxes inside first row exceeds the limit of width it will create another row.

```
display:flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Then in boxes we use `flex-grow: 1` that let every flex child(.box) to grow as much as possible inside their rows.

```css
body{
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background-color: bisque;
  min-height: 100vh;
}



.container{
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: tomato;
  min-height: 70vh;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  max-width:550px;
  margin:0 auto;
  column-gap: 0.5rem;
  row-gap: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}


.box{
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  flex-grow:1;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  height: 10rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.box-fullrow{
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <p>Lorem.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box box-fullrow">
        <p>Lor</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah but does this work also with a tags(link) ? and what if my text is not that long but i want that button to fill the whole row? like extend itself  depending the screen

Comment: links act like same with text and for your second question about whole row i edited the code and add the last box class of `.box-fullrow` than apply that class a `flex-basis:100%` which is basically saying to that box, go and extend 100% of the parent width. That is why it needs to create another row because with other siblings it can not extend 100% @Arsenkho